CUT HERE FOR EXCEPTION DECODER --------------- Exception (0): esp8266
Why does my program end up with CUT HERE FOR EXCEPTION DECODER for esp8266?
I am triying to integrate gps and accelerometers with a website. integrating gps is the hardest one since it always refuse to be connected. gps.location.isValid() and gps.location.isUpdated() not working when all of them combined, but every one of them can work fine on their own.
#include <Wire.h>
#include <MPU6050.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <TinyGPS++.h>

bool zz = false;
int sensor = 1;
float bujur = 1.123456, lintang = 6.654321, maxG_Total_decrement, maxG_Total = 0.0;
#define wifi_ssid "raiden"
#define wifi_pass "12341234"
#define RXPin 14 // sambungkan TX gps ke rx 14
#define TXPin 12 // sambungkan RX gps ke tx 12

MPU6050 mpu;
TinyGPSPlus gps;
StaticJsonDocument<2000> json_web;
SoftwareSerial ss(RXPin, TXPin);

void kirim_data() {
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {
    WiFiClientSecure client;
    client.setInsecure(); // Tidak aman, hanya untuk testing, gunakan sertifikat CA yang valid untuk produksi
    HTTPClient https;
    
    if (https.begin(client, "https://EXAMPLE.com/submit_data.php")) {
      https.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
      
      // Update nilai latitude dan longitude di dalam JSON
      json_web["latitude"] = String(lintang, 6); // Konversi float ke string dengan 6 desimal
      json_web["longitude"] = String(bujur, 6);

      // Tambahkan data sensor ke JSON
      json_web["sensor"] = String(sensor);

      String jsonData;
      serializeJson(json_web, jsonData);

      Serial.println("Start POST...");
      Serial.println(jsonData);

      int httpCode = https.POST(jsonData);

      if (httpCode > 0) {
        if (httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK || httpCode == HTTP_CODE_CREATED) {
          Serial.println("Data sent! Code: " + String(httpCode));
        } else {
          Serial.println("POST failed! Code: " + String(httpCode));
        }
      } else {
        Serial.println("HTTP POST failed! Error: " + https.errorToString(httpCode));
      }

      https.end();
    } else {
      Serial.println("Unable to connect to the server.");
    }
  } else {
    Serial.println("WiFi not connected!");
  }
  json_web.clear();
}

void updateVariables() {
  int16_t ax, ay, az, gx, gy, gz;
  maxG_Total = 0.0; // Reset maxG_Total ke 0 setiap update iterasi
  mpu.getMotion6(&ax, &ay, &az, &gx, &gy, &gz); // mengambil nilai akselerasi dengan library mpu
  float accelScale = 32768.0 / 16; // Accelerometer sensitivity scale factor (LSB/g)
  float ax_g = ax / accelScale;
  float ay_g = ay / accelScale;
  float az_g = az / accelScale;
  float G_begin = sqrt(ax_g * ax_g + ay_g * ay_g + az_g * az_g);

  unsigned long startMillis = millis();
  while (millis() - startMillis < 150 && (G_begin > 2.4)) {
    mpu.getMotion6(&ax, &ay, &az, &gx, &gy, &gz);
    ax_g = ax / accelScale;
    ay_g = ay / accelScale;
    az_g = az / accelScale;
    float G_Total = sqrt(ax_g * ax_g + ay_g * ay_g + az_g * az_g);

    if (G_Total > maxG_Total) {
      maxG_Total = G_Total;
    }
  }

  if (maxG_Total > 13) {
    zz = true;
    float maxG_Total_decrement = maxG_Total;
    Serial.println("sensor mengirim zz");
  }

  maxG_Total_decrement = 0.0;
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  ss.begin(9600);

  delay(300);
  Wire.begin();
  delay(300);
  
  WiFi.begin(wifi_ssid, wifi_pass);
  delay(5000);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println("Mencoba terhubung ke WiFi...");
    delay(2000);
  }

  mpu.initialize();
  mpu.setFullScaleAccelRange(MPU6050_ACCEL_FS_16);
  delay(300);

  Serial.print("Connecting to: ");
  Serial.println(wifi_ssid);
  Serial.println("\nConnected to WiFi!");
}

void loop() {
  // Debugging untuk memastikan loop utama berjalan
 
  while (ss.available() > 0) {
    Serial.println("SS start");
    delay(500);
    if (gps.encode(ss.read())){
      Serial.println("encode start");
      delay(500);
      
         if (gps.location.isUpdated()) {
      Serial.println("Location update:");
      lintang = gps.location.lat();
      bujur = gps.location.lng();
      Serial.print("Latitude: ");
      Serial.println(lintang, 6);
      Serial.println(gps.location.lat());
      Serial.print("Longitude: ");
      Serial.println(bujur, 6);
      Serial.println(gps.location.lng());
    } else {
      Serial.println("Tidak ada update dari GPS");
    }
    
    if (gps.location.isValid()) {
      Serial.println("Location Valid:");
      lintang = gps.location.lat();
      bujur = gps.location.lng();
      Serial.print("Latitude: ");
      Serial.println(lintang, 6);
      Serial.println(gps.location.lat());
      Serial.print("Longitude: ");
      Serial.println(bujur, 6);
      Serial.println(gps.location.lng());
      
    } else {
      Serial.println("Tidak ada valid data dari GPS");
    }

    }
    
 
  }
  
  updateVariables();
  
  if (zz) {
    kirim_data();
    zz = false; // Reset zz for nextdata
  }
  
  delay(1000);
}

and this is the eror message

 --------------- CUT HERE FOR EXCEPTION DECODER ---------------

Exception (0):
epc1=0x4020cec8 epc2=0x00000000 epc3=0x00000000 excvaddr=0x00000000 depc=0x00000000

>>>stack>>>

ctx: sys
sp: 3fffeb80 end: 3fffffb0 offset: 0190
3fffed10:  00000014 00000028 00000003 00000003  
3fffed20:  00000000 000000dd 00000000 3ffedd3b  
3fffed30:  00000000 00000000 00004000 40100600  
3fffed40:  03ac0f00 3fffee15 3fffc228 c0033035  
3fffed50:  00000000 00000001 0000000e 40100b3c  
3fffed60:  00000020 00000030 00000012 ffffffe0  
3fffed70:  40000fb0 00000010 00000521 00000022  
3fffed80:  3fffc200 40100a78 3fffc258 4000050c  
3fffed90:  400046a4 00000030 00000020 ffffffff  
3fffeda0:  40105c7b 00000000 00000000 00000001  
3fffedb0:  04000002 fffffeff 3feffe00 00000100  
3fffedc0:  e690a568 00000001 04000002 00000008  
3fffedd0:  00000000 00000000 60000600 00000030  
3fffede0:  3ffed750 3fffee90 3ffedde0 00000016  
3fffedf0:  402397d8 3fffee90 3ffedc88 3ffed614  
3fffee00:  40239839 3fffee90 3fffee90 ffffff80  
3fffee10:  0000025f 0000024d 00004000 00000100  
3fffee20:  3ffe9ba0 7fffffff 00000000 c0037035  
3fffee30:  00000000 00000001 0000000e 40100b3c  
3fffee40:  00000000 00000000 0000001f 40100600  
3fffee50:  3ffee4c0 3ffef90c 3fffc228 401064a1  
3fffee60:  4000050c 40100a78 3fffc258 4000050c  
3fffee70:  40000f68 00000030 00000010 ffffffff  
3fffee80:  40000f58 00000000 00000020 00000000  
3fffee90:  401021be 4024a954 3ffee498 00000000  
3fffeea0:  40247621 3ffe9104 00000000 3fffdab0  
3fffeeb0:  00000000 3fffdcb0 3ffee4e0 00000030  
3fffeec0:  000000b0 00000016 3ffe85f8 40242994  
3fffeed0:  00000008 00000000 f7ffffff 60000600  
3fffeee0:  00000008 00000000 f7ffffff 40219c45  
3fffeef0:  4024a488 00000008 3ffee4c0 0101f2d2  
3fffef00:  4024a8a2 00505ac6 60000600 60000600  
3fffef10:  0101adff 3ffee4c0 4024a967 3ffe904c  
3fffef20:  3ffee4c0 00507048 3ffee4c0 60000600  
3fffef30:  40251b75 3ffe904c 3ffee4c0 0101adff  
3fffef40:  40251bba 3fffdab0 00000000 3fffdcb0  
3fffef50:  3ffee4e8 40000f65 3fffdab0 00000000  
3fffef60:  40000f49 3ffe9420 3fffdab0 40000f49  
3fffef70:  40000e19 00063cab bff00000 0000bfff  
3fffef80:  00000005 aa55aa55 000000ed 40105d09  
3fffef90:  40105d0f bff00000 0000bfff 1200004b  
3fffefa0:  4010000d bff00000 00063cab 401000ab  
3fffefb0:  40241e44 3fffef4c 40241dfd 3fffff28  
3fffefc0:  3fffffd0 00000000 00000000 feefeffe  
3fffefd0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3fffefe0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3fffeff0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff000:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff010:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff020:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff030:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff040:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff050:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff060:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff070:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff080:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff090:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff0a0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff0b0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff0c0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff0d0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff0e0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff0f0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff100:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff110:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff120:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff130:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff140:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff150:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff160:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff170:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff180:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff190:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff1a0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff1b0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff1c0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff1d0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff1e0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff1f0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff200:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff210:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff220:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff230:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff240:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff250:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff260:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff270:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff280:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff290:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff2a0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff2b0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff2c0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff2d0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff2e0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff2f0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff300:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff310:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff320:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff330:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff340:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff350:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff360:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff370:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff380:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff390:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff3a0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff3b0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff3c0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff3d0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff3e0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff3f0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff400:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff410:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff420:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff430:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff440:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff450:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff460:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff470:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff480:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff490:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff4a0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff4b0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff4c0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff4d0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff4e0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff4f0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff500:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff510:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff520:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff530:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff540:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff550:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff560:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff570:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff580:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff590:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff5a0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff5b0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff5c0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff5d0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff5e0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff5f0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff600:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff610:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff620:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff630:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff640:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff650:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff660:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff670:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff680:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff690:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff6a0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff6b0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff6c0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff6d0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff6e0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff6f0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff700:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff710:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff720:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff730:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff740:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff750:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff760:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff770:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff780:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff790:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff7a0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff7b0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff7c0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff7d0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff7e0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff7f0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff800:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff810:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff820:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff830:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff840:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff850:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff860:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff870:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff880:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff890:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff8a0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff8b0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff8c0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff8d0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff8e0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff8f0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff900:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff910:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff920:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff930:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff940:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff950:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff960:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff970:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff980:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff990:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff9a0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff9b0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff9c0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff9d0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff9e0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff9f0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffa00:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffa10:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffa20:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffa30:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffa40:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffa50:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffa60:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffa70:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffa80:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffa90:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffaa0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffab0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffac0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffad0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffae0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffaf0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffb00:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffb10:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffb20:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffb30:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffb40:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffb50:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffb60:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffb70:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffb80:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffb90:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffba0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffbb0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffbc0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffbd0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffbe0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffbf0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffc00:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffc10:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffc20:  3ffffc64 3ffffc68 3ffef2dc 40214bc4  
3ffffc30:  4025341e 3ffef2dc 00000000 00000001  
3ffffc40:  40254700 feefeffe feefeffe 00000000  
3ffffc50:  3ffef2dc 00000000 3ffef2dc 40214cac  
3ffffc60:  00000000 00000000 00000000 feefeffe  
3ffffc70:  00000000 00000000 000005dc 00000000  
3ffffc80:  00000004 00000000 00000041 3ffffda0  
3ffffc90:  3ffffda8 3ffffda4 3ffefb9c 402503bc  
3ffffca0:  000005dc 00000000 00000010 3fffd85c  
3ffffcb0:  00000000 00000000 00000000 42d60000  
3ffffcc0:  3ffefb9c 00000017 00000018 3ffffd30  
3ffffcd0:  3ffffd30 402516c6 3ffef8f4 3ffffda0  
3ffffce0:  3ffffda8 00000000 4024e077 00000001  
3ffffcf0:  ffffffff 00000000 3ffe9441 00000008  
3ffffd00:  4024e0c6 3fff07cc 3fff07cc 00000000  
3ffffd10:  00000000 00000000 00000020 40100600  
3ffffd20:  000000c0 3fff07cc 00000000 40102970  
3ffffd30:  3ffe92f0 4024d187 3fff07cc 3ffed590  
3ffffd40:  00000000 40237187 3ffed590 3fff07cc  
3ffffd50:  3ffe8ba3 00000000 3ffefb9c 40250410  
3ffffd60:  3fff0864 3ffef8f4 00000006 3ffedcd4  
3ffffd70:  3ffe8ba3 3ffe8ba3 3ffefbcf 40238fc3  
3ffffd80:  3ffedc88 40238b94 4023b204 3ffedc88  
3ffffd90:  401065e5 000417c3 3ffeddb8 00000000  
3ffffda0:  3ffee4c0 3ffeddb8 3ffe85f4 3ffeed24  
3ffffdb0:  0000003a 00000278 00004000 3ffedd80  
3ffffdc0:  3ffeddb8 4023b204 3ffedc88 c0033035  
3ffffdd0:  00000000 00000001 0000000e 40100b3c  
3ffffde0:  0000000b 0000027b 00004000 00000012  
3ffffdf0:  00000280 00000270 00004000 c0037035  
3ffffe00:  00000000 00000001 0000000e 40100b3c  
3ffffe10:  00000000 00000000 0000001f 40100600  
3ffffe20:  402064c0 000000cf 3fffc228 401064a1  
3ffffe30:  4000050c 40100a78 3fffc258 4000050c  
3ffffe40:  4020678a 00000030 00000002 ffffffff  
3ffffe50:  40206785 00000002 00000281 00000008  
3ffffe60:  00000007 00000008 00000000 00000008  
3ffffe70:  000000ff ffffffff 00000000 3ffee97c  
3ffffe80:  3ffefdac 000000dc 0000026f 00000030  
3ffffe90:  00000016 00000008 00000000 00000008  
3ffffea0:  40207848 ffffffff 00000000 3ffe8958  
3ffffeb0:  7ffffffc 3ffe8955 3ffeed4c 00000030  
3ffffec0:  3ffee9f8 3fffdad0 3ffeed4c 00000030  
3ffffed0:  3ffee9f8 3fffdad0 3ffeed4c 00000030  
3ffffee0:  60000314 00000001 3ffeed94 40209ce1  
3ffffef0:  401065e5 00265b82 3ffeed24 00000000  
3fffff00:  3ffee4c0 3ffeed24 3ffe85f4 3ffeed24  
3fffff10:  401065e5 00516f00 3ffeed24 00000000  
3fffff20:  3ffee4c0 3ffeed24 3ffe85f4 3ffeed24  
3fffff30:  000040e5 000001f4 40209124 3fffefb0  
3fffff40:  3ffeed24 000040e5 000001f4 40209279  
3fffff50:  000040e5 000001f4 000040e5 402092ee  
3fffff60:  00000000 000040e5 8b020c49 004b0968  
3fffff70:  402075fc 3ffe8a76 3ffeec94 3ffeed4c  
3fffff80:  3fffdad0 000040e5 000001f4 4020a1f8  
3fffff90:  402075fc 3ffee9f8 3ffeec94 40202606  
3fffffa0:  3fffdad0 00000013 3ffeec94 3ffeed4c  
<<<stack<<<

--------------- CUT HERE FOR EXCEPTION DECODER --------------- 


https://github.com/me-no-dev/EspExceptionDecoder

Your ESP8266 crashed. Exception Decoder (see link by @Juraj) can help you find out what went wrong and at which point in your code this happened.

can you tell me how to use that link sent by him? @StarCat

Just read the "installation" part of the link that jsotola sent you. That explains clearly how to install and use the tool.
